# SQL Server and BETWEEN

Tags: sql, sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I determine in SQL Server if a dateTime range overlaps another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002689/how-can-i-determine-in-sql-server-if-a-datetime-range-overlaps-another)

Hi,
I am trying to determine if a given start time and end time conflicts with another record. I am currently using the following query and if I get 1 or more results I know it has conflicted:

```
 SELECT
    Sheet.SheetID,
    Sheet.StartTime,
    Sheet.EndTime,
FROM
    Sheet
WHERE
    AND @StartTime BETWEEN Sheet.StartTime AND Sheet.EndTime
    OR @EndTime BETWEEN Sheet.StartTime AND Sheet.EndTime
```

This works well but really a user should be able to enter the same start time as a previous end time, ie. last jobs endtime was at 6am, new jobs start time was at 6am. The above query does not allow for this situation.

I have a feeling I may need to use greater than and less than rather than between but would be interested to hear any suggestions.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Using "greater(less) than" is better for performance  so Microsoft recommends this clause. You should use it.

Answer (score 0):

As you already figured out, the `BETWEEN` operator is inclusive (see documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187922.aspx)).

I think you need to do the following:

```
SELECT
    Sheet.SheetID,
    Sheet.StartTime,
    Sheet.EndTime,
FROM
    Sheet
WHERE
    (@StartTime > Sheet.StartTime AND @StartTime < Sheet.EndTime)
    OR (@EndTime > Sheet.StartTime AND @EndTime < Sheet.EndTime)
```

Note that I didn't put in >= or <= operators, as this would prevent the 6am end/6am start situation you want to allow.

**Edit** Just had a thought - what if the new Sheet doesn't start or end within the bounds of an existing Sheet, but there is an entire other sheet contained within it?  Can that happen?  For example, you have one existing Sheet record which starts at 2am and ends at 4am.  You try to insert a new one which starts at 1am and ends at 5am.  Your query (and my original one) would allow this!

You'd have to amend it as follows:

```
SELECT
    Sheet.SheetID,
    Sheet.StartTime,
    Sheet.EndTime,
FROM
    Sheet
WHERE
    (@StartTime > Sheet.StartTime AND @StartTime < Sheet.EndTime)
    OR (@EndTime > Sheet.StartTime AND @EndTime < Sheet.EndTime)
    OR (@StartTime < Sheet.StartTime AND @EndTime > Sheet.EndTime)
```

Answer (score 0):

Define 'conflicts with'...but if you mean 'overlaps', then the condition should be:

```
WHERE @StartTime < Sheet.EndTime AND @EndTime > Sheet.StartTime
```

You can choose '`<=`' or '`>=`' instead of '`<`' or '`>`' if you want exactly the same instant to count.

The condition checks that the value in `@StartTime` comes before the entry in Sheet ended, and that the value in `@EndTime` occurred after the entry in Sheet started.  If both conditions are true, the entry in Sheet overlaps with `@StartTime..@EndTime`.