# how to check if there data range between 2 given dates?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have start time and end time in my application. I now need to check if there is any time falling between those time in SQL Query.

How do I write the query.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should work for you.

```
Select * From MyTable
Where timecreated Between Cast('7/20/08 12:01:01' As DateTime) And Cast('7/20/09 12:01:01' as DateTime)
```

Comment: Shouldn't you cast the dates?

Comment: if i am selecting a time range from 03:00-05:00 pm and if adding the time 03-04:00 then the it is showing correct, but if i am adding the 01:00-03:00 PM, then also it falls under this range.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to not use [between](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187922.aspx) when comparing datetime. The result is often not what you want.

> BETWEEN returns TRUE if the value of
>   test_expression is greater than or
>   equal to the value of begin_expression
>   and less than or equal to the value of
>   end_expression.

Test data for demo

```
declare @T table (dt datetime)

insert into @T values('2011-04-12T09:00:00')
insert into @T values('2011-04-12T10:00:00')
insert into @T values('2011-04-12T11:00:00')
insert into @T values('2011-04-12T12:00:00')
```

Query using between

```
select *
from @T
where dt between '2011-04-12T10:00:00' and '2011-04-12T11:00:00'
```

Result: 11:00 is included in the result.

```
dt
2011-04-12 10:00:00.000
2011-04-12 11:00:00.000
```

Rewrite the query using `>=` and `<` instead.

```
select *
from @T
where
  dt >= '2011-04-12T10:00:00' and
  dt < '2011-04-12T11:00:00'
```

Result

```
dt
2011-04-12 10:00:00.000
```

The title of the question hints at that you want to check for overlapping date intervals. If that is the case you can have a look at this question [How can I determine in SQL Server if a dateTime range overlaps another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002689/how-can-i-determine-in-sql-server-if-a-datetime-range-overlaps-another/5002738#5002738).

Answer (score 0):

This will also work :-

```
 select * from tablename where time between '7/7/2009 12:35:35' and '7/7/2010 23:35:35'
```