# How do I efficiently find all records that DO NOT overlap with a date interval?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, algorithm

Let's say I have a table of hotel_rooms, each with a number of associated reservations records.

The tables would look like this:

**hotel_rooms:**

```
hotel_room_id | hotel_name
--------------------------
1             | Hotel A
2             | Hotel B
3             | Hotel C
```

**reservations:**

```
reservation_id | hotel_room_id | start_date   | end_date
------------------------------------------------------------
1              | 1             | 1 June 2011  | 10 June 2011
2              | 1             | 20 June 2011 | 30 June 2011
3              | 2             | 11 June 2011 | 15 June 2011
4              | 3             | 1 June 2011  | 4 June 2011
```

How can I find all the hotel_rooms with a checkin_date and checkout_date that doesn't overlap with any of the hotel_rooms' reservations?

For example, if the checkin_date was 4 June 2011 and checkout_date was 8 June 2011, then Hotel A and Hotel C wouldn't show up in the results, only Hotel B. If the checkin_date was 16 June 2011 and the checkout_date was 19 June 2011, all three hotels would show up.

I'm sure there are several ways to go about this, but for our situation, let's say there are a lot of records in hotel_rooms and each room is associated with many reservations records. What would be an efficient way to handle this search?

For my purposes, I'm using MySQL and PHP (but I don't necessarily need a solution catered to either).

Comment: Your homework? Why are you re-doing hotels.com?

Comment: Not homework. It's for a site I'm building, which isn't actually for hotels. In this instance, hotels seemed to be the clearest example to use.

Comment: I'm eagerly awaiting a response from OMG Ponies ( aka SQL King) on this one

Comment: Have a look at this answer. I think it does what you are looking for. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002689/how-can-i-determine-in-sql-server-if-a-datetime-range-overlaps-another/5002738#5002738

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT h.*
FROM hotel_rooms h
  LEFT JOIN reservations r
    ON h.hotel_room_id = r.hotel_room_id
   AND checkin_date <= r.end_date
   AND checkout_date >= r.start_date
WHERE r.reservation_id IS NULL
```

or:

```
SELECT *
FROM hotel_rooms h
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM reservations r
    WHERE h.hotel_room_id = r.hotel_room_id
      AND checkin_date <= r.end_date
      AND checkout_date >= r.start_date
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a couple of NOT EXISTS subqueries would work for you.  The timing should not be a problem either, assuming the tables are properly indexed.

```
SELECT *
FROM hotel_rooms
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM reservations 
                  WHERE reservations.hotel_room_id = hotel_rooms.hotel_room_id
                  AND checkin_date BETWEEN start_date AND end_date)
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM reservations 
                WHERE reservations.hotel_room_id = hotel_rooms.hotel_room_id 
                AND checkout_date BETWEEN start_date AND end_date)
```

Comment: I think you miss the case where checkin_date < start_date < end_date < checkout_date for a single booking. Instead I'd propose two simultaneous checks `check_in_date<end_date and check_out_date>start_date`