# Compare Two Dates with Two Other Dates in SqlServer 2008

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, stored-procedures

I have a table in sql server with following schema.

```
   **ID   Title     ActiveFromDate  ActiveToDate**
    1      Test       2013-07-06      2013-08-22
    2      Test       2013-07-01      2013-07-30
```

I want to select the records by ActiveFromDate and Active ToDate, i.e. to select all those record which are between certain date Ranges.

```
     SELECT ISNULL(COUNT(*),0) AS Total, dbo.ArrangementPromotion.Title
FROM dbo.ArrangementPromotion
WHERE(
       (dbo.ArrangementPromotion.ActiveFromDate BETWEEN '2013-08-01' AND '2013-08-14') 
    OR (dbo.ArrangementPromotion.ActiveToDate BETWEEN '2013-08-01' AND '2013-08-14' )
     )
     AND dbo.ArrangementPromotion.Inactive = 0 
     AND dbo.ArrangementPromotion.Deleted = 0
     AND(12 IS NOT NULL OR dbo.ArrangementPromotion.ID <> 12 )
GROUP BY dbo.ArrangementPromotion.Title
```

But i am not getting the desire result if the dates in parameter  @ActiveToDate is less than table Active ToDate. 
Can any body help me in this.

Thanks

Comment: Which rows were you expecting to return?

Comment: First row. as this toDate is between the Dates

Comment: Perhaps something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002689/how-can-i-determine-in-sql-server-if-a-datetime-range-overlaps-another) will work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be looking for something like

```
   (dbo.ArrangementPromotion.ActiveFromDate BETWEEN '2013-08-01' AND '2013-08-14') 
OR (dbo.ArrangementPromotion.ActiveToDate BETWEEN '2013-08-01' AND '2013-08-14' )
OR ('2013-08-01' BETWEEN dbo.ArrangementPromotion.ActiveFromDate AND dbo.ArrangementPromotion.ActiveToDate)
OR ('2013-08-14' BETWEEN dbo.ArrangementPromotion.ActiveFromDate AND dbo.ArrangementPromotion.ActiveToDate)
```

Where `'2013-08-01'` should be `@ActiveFrom` and `'2013-08-14' @ActiveTo`